# Is The Next Act Begins a valid first mythos card during setup?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-the-king-in-yellow

Can the "The Next Act Begins!" Mythos card be a valid first mythos to draw during the game setup? There is no rule prohibiting it, but it would result in no gate emerging at the start of the game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If a mythos card with no gate is drawn during step 14 of
>   Game Setup, discard it and draw again until you draw a
>   mythos card that depicts a gate.

Source: [Arkham Horror Core FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/ca/f0/caf0a739-bda3-4c39-b8cb-a3a915253eb1/arkham_horror__core_faq.pdf) or [Complete Arkham Horror FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/9b/2a/9b2a9f8f-0b42-45ba-bcd2-87dc55c68f5f/complete_arkham_horror_faq.pdf), "Rule Changes and Clarifications" (page 2 in both sources)